# How to iterate inside an iteration?

Tags: rust

So basically, I want to do this

```
for i=0;i<x.len()-1
    for j=i;j<x.len
       //do stuff with x[j] and x[i] at the same time
```

For example, I want to use the same tehnique as sorting using 2 `for` loops, comparing element with element and interchange them. I do not want to sort however, just gave this example for better understanding.

Can i somehow do like:

```
for x in vec.iter()
  for y in x.next()
```

or something like this?

Also, can I somehow remember the position of a certain element while iterating?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can nest `for` loops, but both the examples you give are syntactically invalid. If you're running into a compiler error, try to create a [mre] that shows what you are trying to do and why it doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested code:

```
for x in vec.iter()
    for y in x.next()
```

wouldn't work even if it were syntactically valid because `x` is not an iterator, it's an element of `vec`. To get at the iterator, you need to store it in a variable and desugar the `for` loop into `while let`:

```
let mut iter = v.iter();
while let Some(x) = iter {
    // ...
}
```

Now that we have an explicit `iter`, we can make the inner loop iterate over the remaining items. We can't just iterate over `iter` because that would exhaust it for the outer loop, but we can clone it to obtain a copy of the outer iterator at its current position:

```
let mut iter = v.iter();
while let Some(x) = iter {
    for y in iter.clone() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that we don't need to explicitly call `iter.next()` before the inner loop, as the first item will have already been spent by the outer loop, and the inner loop will naturally observe only the remaining items of each iteration.

Complete code would look like this:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut iter = v.iter();
while let Some(x) = iter.next() {
    println!("x = {}", x);
    for y in iter.clone() {
        println!("    y = {}", y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x = 1
    y = 2
    y = 3
x = 2
    y = 3
x = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use ranges

```
for i in 0..vec.len()-1 {
  for j in i..vec.len() {
    // do something with vec[i] and vec[j]
  }
}
```